# Optimizing Groovy Performance

Tags: performance, groovy, cpu, invokedynamic

I'm working on groovy code perfomance optimization. I've used jvisualvm to connect to running applicaton and gather CPU samples. Samples say that *org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.inkove* takes the most CPU time. I don't see any other application methods in samples.

What is the right way to dig into *CachedMethod.invoke* and understand what code lines really give perfomance penalties?

Thanks.

**UPD**:
I do use **Indy**, it didn't help me.

I didn't try to introduce *@CompileStatic* since I want to find my bottlenecks before rewriting groovy to java.

My problem a bit similar to this thread: [Call site caching faster than invokedynamic?](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Call-site-caching-faster-than-invokedynamic-tp5721659p5721674.html)

I have a code that dynamically composes groovy script. Script template looks this way:

```
def evaluateExpression(Map context){
    def user = context.user
    %s
}
```

where **%s** replaced with

```
user.attr1 == '1' || user.attr2 == '2' || user.attr3 = '3'
```

There is a set (20 in total) of replacements have taken from Databases. 
The code gets replacements from DB, creates GroovyScript and evaluates it.
I suppose the bottleneck is in the script execution. What is the right way to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the *Indy* artifact ?

Comment: Hi, did replace default groovy with *Indy* after submitting the question. Can't say it helped a lot according to newrelic metrics. Now top CPU consumer is **org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$MethodSelector.doCallSiteTargetSet** I assume I did succeed in switching to InvokeDynamic. What should I do with *Selector$MethodSelector.doCallSiteTargetSet* now :) ?

Comment: How about *@CompileStatic* ?

Comment: I would like to avoid randomly rewriting code to make it *@CompileStatic*. I would like to find bottleneck before doing something serious...

Answer (score 0):

So, I've tried various things

1. groovy-indy, doesn't work
2. groovy-indy with some code "optimization", doesn't work. BTW, I'started to play around with try/catch and it as a result I made my "hotspot" run 4 times faster. I'm not good at JVM internals, but internet says - try/catch prevents optimizations. I assumed it as a ground truth. Need to g deeper to understand who it really works.
3. I gave up, turned off invokedynamic and rewrote my "hottest" code with @CompileStatic. It took about 3-4 hours and I my code runs 100 time faster now.

Here are initial metrics with "invokedynamic support"

```
count = 83043

     mean rate = 395.52 calls/second

 1-minute rate = 555.30 calls/second

 5-minute rate = 217.78 calls/second

15-minute rate = 82.92 calls/second

           min = 0.29 milliseconds

           max = 12.98 milliseconds

          mean = 1.59 milliseconds

        stddev = 1.08 milliseconds

        median = 1.39 milliseconds

          75% <= 2.46 milliseconds

          95% <= 3.14 milliseconds

          98% <= 3.44 milliseconds

          99% <= 3.76 milliseconds

        99.9% <= 12.19 milliseconds
```

Here are @CompileStatic metrics with ind turned off. BTW, there is no reason to use @CompileStatic if "indy" is turned on.

```
 count = 139724

     mean rate = 8950.43 calls/second

 1-minute rate = 2011.54 calls/second

 5-minute rate = 426.96 calls/second

15-minute rate = 143.76 calls/second

           min = 0.02 milliseconds

           max = 24.18 milliseconds

          mean = 0.08 milliseconds

        stddev = 0.72 milliseconds

        median = 0.06 milliseconds

          75% <= 0.08 milliseconds

          95% <= 0.11 milliseconds

          98% <= 0.15 milliseconds

          99% <= 0.20 milliseconds

        99.9% <= 1.27 milliseconds
```